# C# TPL Dataflow ReceiveAsync() is not completed but task shows completed

Tags: c#, signalr, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've created TPL Dataflow pipeline as shown below

```
BufferBlock --> TransformBlock --> TransformBlock--> TransformBlock --> BufferBlock
```

For all the data blocks are initialised with `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.EnsureOrdered = true`.

All the blocks are linked correctly as in the above order with `DataflowLinkOptions.PropagateCompletion = true`.

So I am using the dataflow in a way shown like below.

```
public async Task Process(IMessage message)
{
      await (ITargetBlock<IMessage>)firstBlock.SendAsync(message);
      await (ISourceBlock<IMessage>)lastBlock.ReceiveAsync();
}
```

And this method is called and proceeded afterwards as shown below

```
    await Process(message).ContinueWith(task => HandleProcessedMessage(message,task));
```

In one of the transform block the value of `ResponseMessage` (string) property is set (which is inside `IMessage`).

This happens in a SignalR environment. Once we do 0 to 100 messages in a time everything works fine and once we do 499 messages even though the execution reached in `HandleProcessedMessage` method, the `ResponseMessage` property is null. If I add a delay `Task.Delay(500).Wait()` inside the `HandleProcessedMessage`, then after that, the property has its value. Is there something I am missing or is it something related to threading?

I've also verified the value is always set from the transform block as well as no exception occurred. All the requests are processed sequentially inside the pipeline.

Comment: Is any block configured with `BoundedCapacity`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No

Comment: What's the purpose of using the [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) `.ContinueWith` method, over just awaiting the `Process(message)` and then invoking the `HandleProcessedMessage`?

Comment: My guess is that you are launching some fire-and-forget operation inside one of the `TransformBlock<T>`s, either on purpose or by accident. Nothing more to say really, without seeing the code that runs inside the `TransformBlock<T>`s.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tried changing `.ContinueWith` and called the method after await. Same problem still remains. Also in all `TransformBlock` I am just deserializing message and setting the values to IMessage is all I do.

Comment: Could you validate that the message received by the `lastBlock.ReceiveAsync` is the same message sent previously by the `firstBlock.SendAsync`? It should be the same, but you never know.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've validated that the messages in the blocks are the same. Also I'm using Prism eventAggregator to pass the `IMessage` to the class containing `Process` this process method is subscribed initially. Is there a possibility that something messing up using the eventaggregator?

Comment: @mohammedmazin the code you use is weird. If you want to report progress or send a SignalR message after a message is processed, add an ActionBlock at the end that does that. A DataFlow pipeline isn't meant to process a single message at the time. You have no way of knowing if the message you read from the last block has any relation to the one you posted to the first block. If you wanted to only process one message at the time it would be a *lot* simpler to just use an `async` method and `await` every async call

Comment: @mohammedmazin there's no reason to use BufferBlocks at the start and end either, TransformBlock has both an input and output buffer. If you really want to process a stream of messages in a pipeline, remove the head block and replace the tail block with one that  reports progress and talks to SignalR

Comment: I am not familiar with the `EventAggregator` from the Prism library. Could you edit the question and include a minimal example that reproduces the problematic behavior? Preferably without the `EventAggregator`, and with less `TransformBlock<I,O>` blocks. The minimal number of code and components that still has the same problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry for the late reply. I also tried removing buffer blocks at the ends and added an ActionBlock at the end. It definitely made the perfomrance better, but the problem still existed like it happened in 1 out of 15 times. At the end we had to investigate the threading part also which led to the answer posted below.

Comment: *"And this method is called and proceeded afterwards as shown below"* -- Why are you exiting the dataflow pipeline, and then continue processing the same message using low level techniques like the `ContinueWith`? Why don't you just use the TPL Dataflow from start to finish? It seems that you are trying to solve problems that you have created yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If any one looking for the solution. I think the error happens when multiple threads are working together we solved it in a way instead of returning Task Process we changed the method to.

```
public async Task<IMessage> Process(IMessage message)
{
      await (ITargetBlock<IMessage>)firstBlock.SendAsync(message);
      message = await (ISourceBlock<IMessage>)lastBlock.ReceiveAsync();
      return message;
}
```

The method called this was changed to.

```
    IMessage processedMessage = await Process(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    HandleProcessedMessage(processedMessage);
```

This fixed the problems of data being null even after the pipeline. No change was needed in pipeline. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: *"I've validated that the messages in the blocks are the same"* ([from a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71294710/c-sharp-tpl-dataflow-receiveasync-is-not-completed-but-task-shows-completed#comment126068869_71294710)) -- Apparently they are not always the same, otherwise you wouldn't have to change the `Process` method and return `Task<IMessage>` instead of `Task`. So now you have a method that takes a `IMessage` and most of the time returns the same `IMessage`, but sometimes (rarely) returns some other unrelated `IMessage`. How is this a good design?

Comment: Hey Theo! It's possilbe they were exiting their test/console app/main process during `.ContinueWith(task => HandleProcessedMessage(message,task));` fire and forget would mean lost messages. It also means if they were awaiting completion (`PropagateCompletion`) before terminating their app or process or dispose check, they were awaiting only up until the `Pipeline` section was finished... which wouldn't include any `ContinueWith()` executions. `ActionBlocks` with propagate completion/linkages would have caught that mistake though.

This just wasn't good TPL usage per your point.